# How do I resolve this Weak reference issue in Xcode 6.3.2?

Tags: swift, generics, weak-references

I'm getting to grips with Swift coding but I cannot seem to figure out what's wrong with this code.

The goal is to get a working weak list implementation...

My (apparently flawed) implementation always gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at runtime, I guess it must have something to do with swift's reference counting mechanism but I've been staring at this for half a day now...

```
// a singleton test to demo the issue
class WeakListTest : SomeDelegate{

    static let instance = WeakListTest()

    private init(){
        var delegates = WeakList<SomeDelegate>()

        delegates.add(self)

        delegates.foreach({(d) -> Void in
            println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ get some value of our delegate \(d.someString)")  //this gives a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, ...) runtime error

        })
    }

    // SomeDelegate impl
    var someString = "bobo"

}

protocol SomeDelegate : class {
    var someString : String {get set}
}


class SomeWeakList<T:AnyObject> {
    private var list = [SomeWeakWrapper<T>]()

    func add(item: T){
        list += [SomeWeakWrapper(inner: item)]
    }

    func foreach (f : (T) -> Void) {
        list.map({(weakItem) -> Bool in
            if let item = weakItem.inner {
                println("test \(item)")
                f(item)
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        });
    }
}

class SomeWeakWrapper<T:AnyObject> {
    weak private (set) var inner : T?

    init(inner : T){
        self.inner = inner
    }

}
```

You can trigger the behavior simply by getting the singleton instance of WeakListTest

```
WeakListTest.instance
```

The problem goes away when you remove the 'weak' keyword from the 'inner' property of 'SomeWeakWrapper'... but this is obviously not a solution, merely an indicator that is has something to do with reference counting.

Thanks!

Comment: Observation: when I deleted `SomeDelegate` protocol and made `delegates = WeakList<WeakListTest>()`, it worked properly. However I have no idea why it made difference.

Comment: Can't seem to edit my own post on SO (?) ... so I'll post a correction via this comment: The statement that removing the 'weak' keyword resolves the issue is wrong, the issue remains... however if you remove all generic stuff the code works

Comment: oh... and another code error in the example; `var delegates = WeakList<SomeDelegate>()` should be `var delegates = SomeWeakList<SomeDelegate>()` .... sorry for that.

Comment: @JakubVano Yes, good observation... Also if I use the debugger to look at the offending line (runtime error) the funny thing is dat I can perfectly access the property from the debugger, only not from code.

Comment: Another observation is that it is legal to print the delegate in closure in the foreach loop like so `println("@@@ get some value of our delegate \(d)")` which shows that the object referred to by 'd' is indeed correct, only it does not seem to notice that it implements the SomeDelegate protocol and thus does not allow access to the 'someString' property... I don't see what's wrong here.

Comment: The more I look at it the more it seems to be a Swift compiler or runtime bug. If you conditionally cast to SomeDelegate it does pass, however it still throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS when attempting to access the delegate's methods.... (in the foreach loop add `if let d2 = d as? SomeDelegate {
                println(d2.someString)
            }`)